# gcc compilation issue

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

I am trying to compile but getting following error message. I tried to search into google
but was not able to figure out the solution.

```
Creating qmake. Please wait...
g++ -c -o project.o -m64 -pipe -DQMAKE_OPENSOURCE_EDITION -I. -Igenerators 
-Igenerators/unix -Igenerators/win32 -Igenerators/mac -I/tmp/qt-x11-opensource-src-4.2.3
/src/corelib/arch/generic -I/tmp/qt-x11-opensource-src-4.2.3/include -I/tmp/qt-x11-opensource-src-4.2.3/include/QtCore -I/tmp/qt-x11-opensource-src-4.2.3/include -I/tmp/qt-x11-opensource-src-4.2.3/include/QtCore -I/tmp/qt-x11-opensource-src-4.2.3/src/corelib/global -I/tmp/qt-x11-opensource-src-4.2.3/src/3rdparty/md5 -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -I/tmp/qt-x11-opensource-src-4.2.3/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT  project.cpp
project.cpp:1: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
gmake: *** [project.o] Error 1
```

machine name

```
Linux   #1 SMP Sun May 10 18:54:51 MSD 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

g++ -v

```
Target: i386-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --enable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=i386-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)
```

Comment: The message tells you **exactly** what the problem is:  `project.cpp:1: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in`. You're trying to compile for a 64-bit target with a version of the compiler that only does 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compile your program using the -m64 switch when your version of g++ was probably compiled without the 64-bit flag.

Answer (score 0):

Your gcc is compiled for 32 bit mode and you are trying to compile your code for 64 bit mode.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your compiler doesn't support 64 bit memory model.
You may try without -m64 parameter, or install 64-version of the gcc.

Comment: if I do not have access to install 64-version gcc than could I run this program with 32 bit machine

Comment: or is there anyway we can remove m64 . does it impact anything sorry I do hot have much idea what is use of m64